# Add file to package IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following packages in my application:

[image: packages]

Now, I want to add a file in the `templates` package.

How can I achieve this in IntelliJ? I can only add files in the `templates.pages` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select the resources folder, then you create a new file and type `templates/thenameofthefile`.

Or you click the gear icon at the top-right of the view and you de-select the option "Compact middle packages".